# Is there a way to sort blocks of g-code between lines by their highest Z= value?

Tags: python

I'm trying to sort blocks of G-code between C=1 and the next C=1 by each blocks Highest Z= value, and sort each block lowest to highest. I keep getting it to take either just the Z= line or nothing. Below is the G-code I am working with, In this G-code I should be moving G1 Y=412.50 Z=17.1 from below the Z=18.10 to above all other Z=18.10

```
H DX=2440.00 DY=1225.00 DZ=18.00 *MM / "def" -DA T=0 R=1 V=0 C=1  BZ=19.000
XBLOWER E=1# 
; *** [This file has been Post-Processed for Stop Number 10 but contains NO changes.|2023-11-10 Fri  02:17:58.30 PM|(CNC_GCode_PostProc v1.8.745.0);(CNC_GCode_Lib v1.0.389.0);(Common_Lib v1.0.632.0)] ***
F=1
C=1
G0 X=2291.33 Y=1144.00 Z=-1 E=1 T=105
G1 X=2302.50 Z=17.1 
G1 X=2435.00 
G1 Y=884.00 
G1 X=2170.00 
G1 Y=1144.00 
G1 X=2302.50 
G1 X=2313.67 Z=-1 
C=1
G0 X=1625.00 Y=126.33 Z=-1 E=1 T=105
G1 Y=137.50 Z=17.1 
G1 Y=270.00 
G1 X=1885.00 
G1 Y=5.00 
G1 X=1625.00 
G1 Y=137.50 
G1 Y=148.67 Z=-1 
C=1
G0 X=2016.33 Y=1144.00 Z=-1 E=1 T=105
G1 X=2027.50 Z=17.1 
G1 X=2160.00 
G1 Y=884.00 
G1 X=1895.00 
G1 Y=1144.00 
G1 X=2027.50 
G1 X=2038.67 Z=-1 
C=1
G0 X=2017.00 Y=1144.00 Z=-1 E=1 T=105
G1 X=2027.50 Z=18.10 
G1 X=2160.00 
G1 Y=884.00 
G1 X=1895.00 
G1 Y=1144.00 
G1 X=2027.50 
G1 X=2038.00 Z=-1 
C=1
G0 X=1625.00 Y=401.33 Z=-1 E=1 T=105
G1 Y=412.50 Z=17.1 
G1 Y=545.00 
G1 X=1885.00 
G1 Y=280.00 
G1 X=1625.00 
G1 Y=412.50 
G1 Y=423.67 Z=-1 
C=1
G0 X=2292.00 Y=1144.00 Z=-1 E=1 T=105
G1 X=2302.50 Z=18.10 
G1 X=2435.00 
G1 Y=884.00 
G1 X=2170.00 
G1 Y=1144.00 
G1 X=2302.50 
G1 X=2313.00 Z=-1
```

This is the function I'm currently trying to use to sort the block:

```
def sort_blocks(file_path):
    possible_encodings = ['utf-8', 'latin-1']

    for encoding in possible_encodings:
        try:
            with open(file_path, 'r', encoding=encoding) as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
            break
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            continue
    else:
        print(f"Unable to decode file {file_path} with any of the specified encodings.")
        return

    first_line = lines[0].strip()
    dz_match = re.search(r'Z=(\d+\.?\d*)', first_line)
    dz_value = float(dz_match.group(1)) if dz_match else None

    if dz_value not in {12, 18, 12.00, 18.00}:
        print("Invalid DZ value. It should be either 12 or 18.")
        return

    data = []
    in_block = False
    block_data = []
    max_z_value = float('-inf')

    for line in lines[1:]:
        line = line.strip()

        if 'C=1' in line:
            if in_block:
                data.append((max_z_value, block_data))
            in_block = True
            block_data = [line]
            max_z_value = float('-inf')
            continue

        if in_block:
            block_data.append(line)
            z_match = re.search(r'Z=(-?\d+\.?\d*)', line)
            if z_match:
                z_value = float(z_match.group(1))
                max_z_value = max(max_z_value, z_value)

        if '.EOF' in line:
            in_block = False
            block_data.append(line)
            data.append((max_z_value, block_data))
            block_data = []
            max_z_value = float('-inf')

    if in_block:
        data.append((max_z_value, block_data))

    data.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

    with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(first_line + '\n')
        for _, block in data:
            f.write('\n'.join(block) + '\n')
```

Comment: Have you checked out https://pypi.org/project/pygcode/ and/or https://pypi.org/project/gcodeparser/

Comment: wouldn't gcodeparser work similar to a pandas dataframe?

Comment: maybe, I'm don't really know anything about either package but a proper parser might help you get to a place where sorting was trivial.

Comment: I'll look into it, I think the issue is that its losing the DZ value its looking for somewhere in the function

Comment: I keep having a issue with it actually trying to compare the Z value inside a block vs other blocks and sort them off that, I can get the entire list and separate them into blocks.

Comment: Whats the issue you are having, whats the expect ouput vs what you are getting? I tested your code, and it seems to sort properly based on how you described it. The blocks with the highest Z value (18.10) are at the bottom of all the blocks.

Comment: ok, well it seems to be something with the rest of the program, I didn't even think of just running the single function due to the setup needed to get that info. Thank you